# how to create points in postgres from array of lan and lat points

Tags: perl, postgresql

I have arrays of latitude and longitude . Now I want to create array of points from that. How can I do that in postgresql?
I am writing something like this which is not working.

```
my $data = { 
  type => 'Feature',
  geometry => {
    type => "Point",
    coordinates => [@lon[0],@lat[0]]
  }
};
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What about postgres? How is it connected to your question?

Comment: `@lon[0]`is weird, even if we don't know about the definitions before your code. Didn't you want to write `$lon[0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

In Perl 5, the sigil (`$@%&*` in front of a variable name) indicates not the type of the variable you are working with, but the something more like the type you are expecting as a result of your value access. This is important as one and the same statement in Perl can evaluate different depending on list vs. scalar context.

I.e. if we have an array `@a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and the first element is the *scalar* `1`, then we would access it as `$a[0]`.

However, you can access multiple elements at once: `@a[0 .. 2, -1]` would return a *list*  `(1, 2, 3, 5)`, so this is the *only* case where we access array elements with the `@` sigil.

So while writing `@lat[0]` and `@lon[0]` is sometimes possible when using Perl with `no strict`, this is somewhat bad style and should always be written as `$lon[0]` and `$lat[0]`.

If you construct your `$data` inside a loop and don't need the `@lat` and `@lon` afterwards, you could `shift` the first element from the array.

```
while (@lat and @lon) { # a condition is a scalar context — evaluates to array *length*
  my $data = {
    type     => 'Feature',
    geometry => {
      type        => 'Point',
      coordinates => [shift @lon, shift @lat],
    },
  };
  # insert data point
}
```

This loop runs as long as there are elements in `@lat` *and* `@lon`. However, modelling the coordinates as a seperate `lon` and `lat` values might make the insertion into the DB easier and your data better retrievable:

```
   geometry => {
      type => 'Point',
      lon  => (shift @lon),
      lat  => (shift @lat),
   },
```